# Hibernate Deleting Members of a Set in a One To Many Relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

I understand that this is a reasonably common problem with Hibernate, however I am still struggling to write code that functions correctly.  Basically, I have two classes; Demographic and NextOfKin.  The later is related to Demographic as a One-To-Many Set.  Simplified:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
          <class name="entities.Demographic" table="Demographics">

            <id name="id" type="long" column="Id" ><generator class="identity"/></id>
            <set name="nextOfKinList" table="NextOfKin" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all,delete-orphan" >
                <key><column name="DemographicId" not-null="true" /></key>
                <one-to-many class="entities.NextOfKin" />
            </set>
         </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="entities.NextOfKin" table="NextOfKin">
            <id name="id" type="long" column="Id" ><generator class="identity"/></id>  
            <many-to-one name="demographic" class="entities.Demographic" fetch="select">
                <column name="DemographicId" not-null="true" />
            </many-to-one>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The code I am trying to use remove the list of NextOfKin follows - again simplified:

```
    try {
        DAOFactory factory = DAOFactory.instance(DAOFactory.HIBERNATE);
        HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
        Demographic demographic = factory.getDemographicDAO().findDemographic();        

        if (!demographic.getNextOfKinList().isEmpty()) {
            for (Iterator<NextOfKin> iterator = demographic.getNextOfKinList().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                NextOfKin nextOfKin = iterator.next();
                factory.getNextOfKinDAO().delete(nextOfKin);
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
        demographic.setNextOfKinList(nextOfKinList);
        HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
    }
    finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }
```

I have tried several approaches, but all have failed either leaving the relationship intact or as with the current example throwing an Exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: entities.Demographic.nextOfKinList
```

Apologies as this is a fairly standard question, but any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need clear the set: `demographic.getNextOfKinList().clear()`. Hibernate will automatically delete the elements from the database, this is the role of `delete-orphan`.

```
if (!demographic.getNextOfKinList().isEmpty()) {
     demographic.getNextOfKinList().clear();      
}
```

And remove the line: `demographic.setNextOfKinList(nextOfKinList);` If you want to add new elements to the collection, add them to the existing collection:

`demographic.getNextOfKinList().add(newElem)`

Comment: fyi in xml config that would be  cascade="all-delete-orphan"  and it works

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deleting them one by one try this.

```
demographic.getNextOfKinList().clear();

demographic.getNextOfKinList().addAll(nextOfKinList);
```